# Multi file upload with rails_admin (Carrierwave, Paperclip, Dragonfly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, carrierwave, rails-admin, dragonfly-gem

I'm looking for a quick solution for multi file upload with rails_admin.

Any ideas or solutions out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I'd take here is to develop a custom action which would include it's own view and controller processing.

You can generate a rails_admin plugin with the directions at the top of the page [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action).

And here are some examples of custom actions I've built out:

- [Import](https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import)
- [Print to PDF](https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_pdf)

The import plugin has a supporting blog article [here](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/02/railsadmin-import-part-2.html). [This](https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import/blob/master/lib/rails_admin_import.rb) is the file you want to look at where you add your upload behavior inside the :controller instance option.