# Customize rails_admin to include self-created views and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I started using rails_admin engine lately and can't quite figure out how I can add my own pages to it. My requirement exactly is that I have a controller and view that fetches all the available mongoDb collections and displays at

> http://localhost:3000/mongo/collections

Is it possible to merge this view somehow with rails admin so that I get a link as

> http://localhost:3000/admin/mongo

I am not using ActiveRecords or models. I'm fetching the data from HTTP request and displaying it. Ideally, I need a tab for my page just below the default dashboard tab. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I tried the answer and got stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display this as a tab, take a look at RailsAdmin's new [custom actions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action).

I just gave some examples and links in my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517358/multi-file-upload-with-rails-admin-carrierwave-paperclip-dragonfly/9222944#9222944).

---

If you don't want to add this functionality as a custom action, you can:

- Map a route to your controller & action
- Have your controller inherit from RailsAdmin MainController and write code for your action
- Include a view for your action
- Copy a RailsAdmin view over to add it in as a tab

However, I'd recommend the custom action approach because it does not require you to keep your copied RailsAdmin view updated.

Comment: I have issue on step 2. The controller requires a model (in the to_model_name method). How do I make it work without model?