# RailsAdmin Custom Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I'm writing a custom rails_admin controller (Backend::ImagesController) which inherits from RailsAdmin::MainController.

I followed the steps [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845480/customize-rails-admin-to-include-self-created-views-and-controllers), but I'm getting an undefined_method error when my view uses the route helper backend_image_path(@image).

The controller is defined under controllers/backend/images_controller.rb as:

```
module Backend
  class ImagesController < RailsAdmin::MainController
    #layout 'rails_admin/cropper'

    skip_before_filter :get_model
    skip_before_filter :get_object
    skip_before_filter :check_for_cancel

    .... the various actions ....
```

My routes are defined as:

```
namespace 'backend' do
  resources :images do
    member do
      get :cropper
      post :crop
    end
  end
end

mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/backend', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

And the output of rake routes is what I expect:

```
backend_image GET  /backend/images/:id(.:format) backend/images#show {:protocol=>"https://"}
```

Finally, from rails console:

```
app.backend_image_path(id: 10)
=> "/backend/images/10"
```

This controller worked flawlessly until I tried to integrate it in RA by having it extend RailsAdmin::MainController

I do not know why the route_helper is not accessible from the controller anymore....

Comment: if you planning for more customizations in future, activeadmin would help.

Comment: I am not considering to switch to another framework, anyway I pretty much figured out how to do this. Tomorrow I will answer my own question.

Comment: @Cec do you mind answering this question?

Comment: @thedeeno Hi! since I cannot answer my question, I edited it to include the solution at the bottom.
I hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: @thedeeno Was my solution useful to you?

Comment: @Cec Thanks for taking the time to update this. I'm not working on this project atm but I'll be sure to check back here when I dust it off. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

My mistake was the **namespace** of my custom controller: although RA engine is mounted on **/backend**, its namespace is still **RailsAdmin**.

This means that to have a custom controller in my backend, I have to create the controller under namespace **RailsAdmin**, thus

```
module RailsAdmin
   class ImagesController < RailsAdmin::MainController     

       # unless your controller follows MainController routes logic, which is 
       # unlikely, these filters will not work 

       skip_before_filter :get_model
       skip_before_filter :get_object
       skip_before_filter :check_for_cancel

       ....
   end
end
```

The controller is defined under **controllers/rails_admin/images_controller.rb** and views are in **views/rails_admin/images/**

**Routing**

Having a custom RA controller, implies drawing new routes for the engine itself, thus my routes.rb becomes like this:

```
RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.draw do
   # here you can define routes for the engine in the same way you do for your app

   # your backend must be under HTTPS
   scope protocol: 'https://', constraints: {protocol: 'https://'} do
      resources :images
   end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
   # your application's routes
   .....
end
```

To access the new engine routes (e.g. images INDEX):

```
rails_admin.images_path
```

An important RA wiki page for routes is [this one](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Using-RailsAdmin-routes)

Comment: thankx for posting your answer... it really helped a lot...
but I am getting this error:
 `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'breadcrumb_parent' for nil:NilClass):`
it is on this line:
 `while action.breadcrumb_parent && (action = action(*action.breadcrumb_parent)) # rubocop:disable Loop`

Comment: @VoidZero first of all, I'm running this on RailsAdmin 0.7. I don't know if I can be of help, but without better information I won't be for sure. I suggest that you specify your RA and Rails versions and that you put the stack-trace of your error on http://pastebin.com/  and post the link here.