# rails+rails admin override action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rails-admin

i'm using rails_admin gem, is possible to override an action of a specific controller like this:

I'm using the InheritedResources gem by josevalim https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

this is the controller for the "normal" user.

```
class EventsController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def create
    staff=Staff.find(params[:event][:author_id])
    staff.create_user(name: staff.name,email:staff.email) unless staff.user
    create!
  end
end
```

I want to override the create action of the rails_admin controller for the Event model, as I  have just override a "normal" controller.
Is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [create a custom action](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/03/15/railsadmin-custom-action-case-study) and use it instead of `create` action. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9222972/6733955) is helpful too.
Quote from it:

- Map a route to your controller & action
- Have your controller inherit from RailsAdmin MainController and write code for your action
- Include a view for your action