# Rails admin - Customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Recently I started using Rails Admin for creating admin panel for my project. The UI for rails admin is very nice and it gives a good user experience also. I had some concerns with customizing rails admin like overriding the controller action and using custom views. For instance, suppose I need to clone a record and use it for edit action. Is it possible?
Can we use custom views or forms?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845480/customize-rails-admin-to-include-self-created-views-and-controllers answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Well, defining a new action is pretty simple with RailsAdmin. You can also override views for any controller and etc. However, it's a bit hard to use built-in code for your controller actions (for example, if you want to re-use the Update action code - it will cost you some time).

So, where to start? This tutorial explains how to create a simple action (it will have separate button in RailsAdmin, but it won't render any template) http://fernandomarcelo.com/2012/05/rails-admin-creating-a-custom-action/

After that, you might need to create a more complex action (something like Edit/Update combination or something else). This is were reading source code will help you. This is where you find all RailsAdmin actions: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions.
They are defined in a very similar manner with examples from a previous tutorial. After all that, you will find out that these actions are much alike to actions of any Rails controller.

Now you're ready to write any custom action!